# Подскажите, почему в колбеке переменная $day равна NULL?

Tags: php, callback, замыкания

```
    $day = 5;

    $result = array_filter($masConfig['PACKET_ADS_DAY'], function($innerArray){
        global $day;
        return ($innerArray[0] == $day); 
    });

    var_dump($result);
```

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, почему в колбеке $day равна  NULL ? Где искать причину ? Спасибо !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что в **[Анонимныx функциях](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php)** переменные извне передаются через оператор `use`:

```
$day = 5;

$result = array_filter($masConfig['PACKET_ADS_DAY'], function($innerArray) use($day)
{
    return ($innerArray[0] == $day); 
});

var_dump($result);
```